# Dynamically created GridView Template Columns face a small glitch: no PAGING?

Tags: c#, .net, gridview, datatable, paging

I dynamically create my gridView from DataTable. Now when I add paging to it, I must Auto Generate Columns. As soon as I do that, the gridview data is duplicated.

1.5K+ records each 150 Columns duplicated doesn't exactly look quite right.

Anyone's got a clue on how to add paging that actually won't mess everything up?

PS: I fire up LoadGridView() event on Button_Click.

[This is a very simple example on how it is done](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13462/How-to-create-template-columns-dynamically-in-a-gr?msg=4223518#xx4223518xx)